# List of calculation rules for asymptotic notation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, computational-complexity

Background: I am working my way through CLR/CLRS's proof of the master theorem (section 4.4 in the 1st and 2nd editions of [Introduction to Algorithms](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms)), and I'm doing my own write-up of this proof<sup>1</sup> where I make clear what theorems are used, specifically the theorems about asymptotic notation.

As one example, I discovered that this proof when proving (4.13) (this part has been dropped in the 2nd edition) silently uses the fact that $\;f(x) = O(1) \text{ for } x \to \infty\;$ implies $\;g(f(x)) = \Theta(1) \text{ for } x \to \infty\;$, if $\;f \in \mathbb R \to \mathbb N\;$ and $\;g \in \mathbb N \to \mathbb R\;$.

There are of course many more such rules, like $\;f(x) = O(g(x))\;$ implies $\;f(x) + g(x) = O(g(x))\;$, etc.

My question: Where can I find an overview list of such 'calculation rules' for asymptotic notation?

<sub><sup>1</sup>In [Dijkstra-Scholten](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD13xx/EWD1300.html) and [Gries-Schneider](https://www.springer.com/computer/theoretical+computer+science/book/978-0-387-94115-8)'s calculational proof style, in response to [a 17 year old challenge](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sci.math/Vxw1xykW_D0/bj_akPQE-g4J) by [Brian Borchers](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6310/brian-borchers).</sub>

Comment: What kind of resource do you have?  (I get the vibe, and I hope I'm wrong, that you're looking for something a bit more specific than exists; something like "These people used 253+621=874 as a fact, but I've never seen that published; where's a list of all the addition facts".)

Comment: @tabstop :-) Well, the rules I'm looking for are a bit more general than that.  Roughly at the same level as http://math.stackexchange.com/q/18800/11994, or the integration/differentiation rules overview I've seen in the appendix of a basic Calculus book.

Comment: Commentless downvoter: What do you think is wrong with this question? How can I improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really goes back to the definition. For Big-O, we have $|f(x)| \leq c * |g(x)|$, for $c \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $x \geq k$ for $k \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$. Big-Omega is when we switch the inequalities, and Big-Theta is the equivalence relation.

Another basic are that polynomials of a higher power always dominate. Exponentials dominate polynomials. And if I have two exponentials $2^{x}$ vs. $3^{x}$, the higher base wins out.

Other than the basic ordering and limit rules, small rules like this (if you want I will write them out, but I am assuming you have those), and the Master Theorem, there really aren't a bunch of quick rules as you are seeking. With Calculus, a lot of the derivative and integral rules need to simply be memorized. That's not the case with asymptotics. Here, they require some thinking and clever substitutions more often than not.

So with your example above, if we know $f(n) = O(g(n))$ and we are given $f(n) + g(n)$. Since Big-O is a weak-inequality, we have $g(n) = O(g(n))$. By assumption, $f(n) = O(g(n))$. So we have $f(n) + g(n) \to 2O(g(n)) = O(g(n))$. If we didn't know $f(n) = O(g(n))$, then $f(n) + g(n) = O(max\{f(n), g(n)\}) = O(f(n) + g(n))$.

I did find this link with some basic rules, but if you're proving the Master Theorem, I'm sure you are familiar with these: [http://www.augustana.ualberta.ca/~hackw/csc210/exhibit/chap04/bigOhRules.html](http://www.augustana.ualberta.ca/%7Ehackw/csc210/exhibit/chap04/bigOhRules.html) ([Wayback Machine link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180303205922/http://www.augustana.ualberta.ca/%7Ehackw/csc210/exhibit/chap04/bigOhRules.html)).

Hope this helps some. Sorry it's not more along the lines of what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

A [handout on big $O$ notation](https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Eblanchem/250/2017/Lecture12_handouts.pdf) ([WayBack Machine link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210930204111/https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Eblanchem/250/2017/Lecture12_handouts.pdf)), made by Mathieu Blanchette*, has a few more rules at the end of page two.

This is part of [COMP250](http://cs.mcgill.ca/%7Eblanchem/250/) Winter 2017 course material which also has related information.

*Mathieu Blanchette is a faculty member of McGill University.

Comment: I happened to choose the other slightly more extensive answer for the bounty, but I also appreciate 'your' list.  Thanks!